# Need help in Java

Tags: java

Im having problem with java and i need help.

Assume the existence of an interface, GUIComponent with the following methods: - open and close: no parameters, returns boolean - move and resize: accepts two integer parameters and returns void
 Define a class, Window, that implements the GUIComponent interface, and has the following members: - width, height, xPos, and yPos integer instance variables, with xPos and yPos initialized to 0 - a constructor that accepts two integer variables (width followed by height) which are used ti initialize the width and height instance variables - An implementation of open: that sends "Window opened" to System.out, and returns true - An implementation of close that sends "Window closed" to System.out, and returns true - An implementation of resize that modifies the width and height variables to reflect the specified size - An implementation of move that modifies xPos and yPos to reflect the new position

This is the code i typed.

```
public class Window implements GUIComponent{
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int xPos = 0;
    private int yPos = 0;
    public Window(int width, int height){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
    public boolean open(){
        System.out.println("Window opened");
        return true;
    }
    public boolean close(){
        System.out.println("Window closed");
        return true;
    }
    public void resize(int width, int height){
        this.width = x;
        this.height = y;
    }
    public int move(int xPos, int yPos){
        xPos = 1;
        yPos = 1;
    }
}
```

And I'm getting errors, i don't know what to do.

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error: You might want to use a number other than 1

Comment: Read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). One bullet point: _If your program throws an exception, have you included the exception, with both the message and the stack trace?_

Answer (score 1):

Here's one issue - Look at this method

```
public int move(int xPos, int yPos) {
   xPos = 1;
   yPos = 1;
}
```

It has no return value. The method name `move` suggests that it is an action method and should be declared as `void`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Reimeus's suggestion, a few things I see:

Change

```
public void resize(int width, int height){
    this.width = x; // What is x???
    this.height = y;  // What is y???
}
```

To

```
public void resize(int width, int height){
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}
```

Also change

```
public int move(int xPos, int yPos){
    xPos = 1; // You should change the class variable. use  this
    yPos = 1; // and I thing you want the value to be passed by the method 
}
```

to

```
public void move(int xPos, int yPos){
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
}
```